# PHP sqlsrv PDOStatement::rowCount

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv, rowcount

I have a problem with the `rowCount()` in this code:

```
$sqlLoc= "
          DECLARE @Data2 AS DATE; 
          SET @Data2 = CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(date, '$dataFine'), 102);
          
          DECLARE @Data1 AS DATE;
          SET @Data1 = CONVERT(DATE,CONVERT(date, '$dataInizio'), 102);
          
          SELECT noteincassi.CodLocale,Insegna,Citta
          FROM [Edera].[dbo].[NoteIncassi]
          JOIN edera.dbo.AnagraficaLocali ON AnagraficaLocali.CodLocale=NoteIncassi.CodLocale
          WHERE DataIncasso >= @Data1  AND DataIncasso <= @Data2 AND tipoincasso = '6' AND sospeso = 0
          GROUP BY noteincassi.CodLocale,insegna,Citta
          ORDER BY Insegna";
$queryLoc = $conn->prepare($sqlLoc,array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
$queryLoc->execute();

echo $numero=$queryLoc->rowCount();

echo "<h1>MEDIA INCASSI DAL ".date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dataInizio))." AL ".date('d-m-Y',strtotime($dataFine))."</h1>";

$id=0;
while($resultLoc=$queryLoc->fetch()){
```

It will print `-1`, but the fecth is working and rows are returned, so the rest of the code is working fine, it's only the `rowCount()` and I don't understand why.

Thank you

Comment: It's not going to get a result until you finish fetching all the data. And why don't you just implement a counter in your `while` loop? Side note: do *not* inject the dates, pass them through as proper parameters using `bindParam`

Comment: It does not have to fetch all data to work, i have another code working fine and return the rows number before the fetch, so i think it's somenthing in the query.

Comment: Are you asking or telling? There is no way a fully streaming query plan would be able to do that. It could be the other query plan has a blocking operator or something

Comment: I'm telling you. The other code is working and returning the number of rows before the fetch. Also on the officiale MS page [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/connect/php/pdostatement-rowcount?view=sql-server-ver15) in the example you can see that right after the execution they call the rowCount without fetching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using PHP Driver for SQL Server (based on the question's title and the link in the comments) and it seems that you need the `PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_CURSOR_SCROLL_TYPE => PDO::SQLSRV_CURSOR_BUFFERED` option in the `PDO::prepare()` call.

This is briefly explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/cursor-types-pdo-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#pdo_sqlsrv-and-client-side-cursors): *You can request a client-side cursor by using PDO::prepare, specifying the PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL cursor type, and then specifying PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_CURSOR_SCROLL_TYPE => PDO::SQLSRV_CURSOR_BUFFERED*.

I'm able to reproduce (and solve) this unexpected behaviour using the following code (based on the code in the question):

```
$sql = "
    DECLARE @Data2 AS DATE; 
    SET @Data2 = GETDATE();
    
    DECLARE @Data1 AS DATE;
    SET @Data1 = GETDATE();

    SELECT A, B
    FROM (VALUES (11, 22), (33, 44)) v (A, B)
";
$statement = $conn->prepare(
    $sql, 
    array(
        PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL, 
        PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_CURSOR_SCROLL_TYPE => PDO::SQLSRV_CURSOR_BUFFERED
    )
);
$statement->execute();
echo $numero = $statement->rowCount();
```

One important note - always use parameters in your statement to prevent possible SQL injection issues:

```
<?php

... 
$sqlLoc = "
    DECLARE @Data2 AS DATE; 
    SET @Data2 = CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(date, :dataFine), 102);
    
    DECLARE @Data1 AS DATE;
    SET @Data1 = CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(date, :dataInizio), 102);
    
    SELECT noteincassi.CodLocale, Insegna,Citta
    FROM [Edera].[dbo].[NoteIncassi]
    JOIN edera.dbo.AnagraficaLocali ON AnagraficaLocali.CodLocale=NoteIncassi.CodLocale
    WHERE DataIncasso >= @Data1  AND DataIncasso <= @Data2 AND tipoincasso = '6' AND sospeso = 0
    GROUP BY noteincassi.CodLocale,insegna,Citta
    ORDER BY Insegna
";
$statement = $conn->prepare(
   $sql, 
   array(
      PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL, 
      PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_CURSOR_SCROLL_TYPE => PDO::SQLSRV_CURSOR_BUFFERED
   )
);
$queryLoc->bindParam(':dataFine', $dataFine);
$queryLoc->bindParam(':dataInizio', $dataInizio);
$queryLoc->execute();   
...

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm aware of sql injection but these variable are result from a previous query so it's not possible to inject.
Plus the webserver is only available in the lan of my company without external access.